# Sorting CSV strings in array excluding zero index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have comma separated values in a array which I am getting from a CSV file and using it to display a table in React.

```
[
"Company,Industry,Years,CEO", 
"Tesla,Automobile,15,Elon", 
"SpaceX,AeroSpace,17,Elon", 
"Amazon,Software,24,Jeff", 
"Google,Software,20,Sundar", 
"Microsoft,Software,30,Satya", 
"BMW,Automobile,103,Harald", 
"BlueOrigin,AeroSpace,19,Jeff", 
"NASA,Space,61,Gov", 
"Hyperloop,Transportation,5,Elon"
]
```

**JSX**

```
  renderCsvTable() {
        const { file } = this.state;
        if(file !== "") {
          let data = `<table className="csv-table">`;
          file.forEach((cells, i) => {
            let cell_data = cells.split(',');
            data+= `<tr>`;
            cell_data.forEach((column) => {
              if (i === 0) {
                data+= `<th>${column}</th>`;
              } else {
                data+= `<td>${column}</td>`;
              }
            });
            data+= `</tr>`;
          });
          data+= `</table>`;

          return (
            <div>{ parse(data) }</div>
          )
        }
      }
```

I want to sort my array according to individual column.

Currently I can sort by first column using sort method

```
this.state.file.sort((a, b) => (a > b) - (a < b));
```

But it's also sorting the `[0] index` of the array which I don't want to because it's the header of the table.

**After Sorting**

```
[
"Amazon,Software,20,Jeff", 
"BMW,Automobile,33,Harald", 
"BlueOrigin,Space,4,Jeff", 
"Company,Industry,Years,CEO", 
"Google,Software,30,Sundar", 
"Hyperloop,Transportation,5,Elon", 
"Microsoft,Software,30,Satya", 
"NASA,Space,60,Gov", 
"SpaceX,Space,5,Elon", 
"Tesla,Automobile,10,Elon"
]
```

Also I want to sort column wise like if I click on **Years** or **CEO** it should sort by years or CEO. Same with every column.

Comment: Expected output please?

Comment: When I click on the header whose columns are Company, Industry, Years and CEO it should sort the rest of the array excluding the `0th index` which is the header in state according to the column clicked. If I click on Company, sort the array according to Company and if I click on Years, sort the array according to years.

Comment: I have answer the question with giving general function which take array of strings and column no on which you want to sort. Tell me if there is a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend building the html elements in the `render()` function. Doing this will give you access to React's data binding and event listening syntax, make it easier to maintain, and increase performance on large tables.

This can be done by parsing the CSV data into an Object and storing it into `this.state.data`. The key being the header and the value being the data point.

```
this.state.data =[
  {'Company':'Tesla','Industry':'Automobile','Years':'15','CEO':'Elon'},
  {'Company':'SpaceX','Industry':'AeroSpace','Years':'17','CEO':'Elon'},
  {'Company':'NASA','Industry':'Space','Years':'61','CEO':'Gov'}
];

  // on click of table heading and pass the key to sort based on (ex. company)
  sortBy(key) {
    let arrayCopy = [...this.state.data];
    arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key));
    this.setState({data: arrayCopy});
  }


  compareBy(key) {
    return function (a, b) {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
      return 0;
    };
  }
```

Here is my solution: https://codepen.io/brettdawidowski/pen/drJEjb

I hope this helps!

```
// babel.js

/*
 * Row Component
*/

const Row = (rows) => (
  <tr>
    {
      // Maping the values of Object to HTML <td>
      // **Note: Assuming the Keys/Values will persist in the same order
      Object.values(rows).map((r) => <td>{r}</td>)
    }  
  </tr>
);

/*
  Table Component
*/
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        // Example Input: 
       // {'Company':'Tesla','Industry':'Automobile','Years':'15','CEO':'Elon'},
       // {'Company':'SpaceX','Industry':'AeroSpace','Years':'17','CEO':'Elon'},
      // {'Company':'NASA','Industry':'Space','Years':'61','CEO':'Gov'}

      ],
      // Add service/ajax call to http GET request to fetch csv from server/back-end
      file: [
      "Company,Industry,Years,CEO", 
      "Tesla,Automobile,15,Elon", 
      "SpaceX,AeroSpace,17,Elon", 
      "Amazon,Software,24,Jeff", 
      "Google,Software,20,Sundar", 
      "Microsoft,Software,30,Satya", 
      "BMW,Automobile,103,Harald", 
      "BlueOrigin,AeroSpace,19,Jeff", 
      "NASA,Space,61,Gov", 
      "Hyperloop,Transportation,5,Elon"
      ]
    };

    this.parseCsv();

    this.compareBy.bind(this);
    this.sortBy.bind(this);
  }

  parseCsv() {
    const { file } = this.state;
    if(file !== "") {

      // set headers from index 0
      let headers = file[0].split(',').map(value => value);

      // temp remove index 0 from For loop
      file.slice(1).forEach((row) => {
        let items = row.split(',');
        let d = {};
        items.forEach((item, index) => {
          // parse Numbers for proper sorting ex. “3” -> 3
          if(/^[0-9]+$/.test(item)) item = parseInt(item)
          // key: Company, value: Tesla
          d[headers[index]] = item;

          // When complete parsing add to state.data
          if(index + 1 === items.length) {
            this.state.data.push(d);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
          }
        })
      })

    }
  }


  compareBy(key) {
    return function (a, b) {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
      return 0;
    };
  }

  sortBy(key) {
    let arrayCopy = [...this.state.data];
    arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key));
    this.setState({data: arrayCopy});
  }

  render() {
    const headers = Object.keys(this.state.data[0])
    const rows = this.state.data.map( (rowData) => <Row {...rowData} />);

    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            headers.map((h) => <th onClick={() => this.sortBy(h)}>{h}</th> )
          }
        </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
          { rows }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );

  }
}

/*
 * Render Component
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution too, however the years column is not getting sorted correctly.

Comment: Nice catch! It’s sorting by charCode and not Number value for years. I’ll edit the post to fix that bug.

Comment: Hi can you make your code to not use hardcoded values both in `<th>` and `const Row`. Your code breaks if you use a different CSV file. I will accept your answer if it's possible.

Comment: Yes it should just be a minor update. I’ll follow up when it’s added

Comment: I updated the code snippet and codepen to make the rows to be dynamic rather than being hardcoded for this specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that.

1. Firstly convert array of strings to array of array
2. Then use `slice(1)` to get all the rows excluding headers
3. apply `sort()` on the rows returned by `slice(1)`
4. The function show take a parameter `colno`.
5. In the `sort()` you should compare the values at `colno`
6. Before returning add the headers `arr[0]` before the sorted array.

```js
let arr = [
"Company,Industry,Years,CEO", 
"Tesla,Automobile,15,Elon", 
"SpaceX,AeroSpace,17,Elon", 
"Amazon,Software,24,Jeff", 
"Google,Software,20,Sundar", 
"Microsoft,Software,30,Satya", 
"BMW,Automobile,103,Harald", 
"BlueOrigin,AeroSpace,19,Jeff", 
"NASA,Space,61,Gov", 
"Hyperloop,Transportation,5,Elon"
]
function sort(arr,colno){
  let x = arr.map(x => x.split(',').map(a => Number(a) || a));
  return [x[0]].concat(x.slice(1).sort((a,b) => {
    if(typeof a[colno] === 'number'){
      return a[colno] - b[colno];
    }
    else return a[colno].localeCompare(b[colno]);
  })).map(x => x.join(','))
  
}
console.log(sort(arr,1))
```

Comment: Accepted codedawi's answer as his answer provides solution for creating jsx with event handlers too.